Telegram BOT command in GoogleAppScript not triggerred
I have a problem with my code where the command is not triggerred properly. Here's my code.
function handleInitialCommands(receivedTextMessage, chatId, messageId) {
  if (receivedTextMessage.toLowerCase() === '/daftarsimluh') {
    startCekNIK(chatId, messageId);
  } else if (receivedTextMessage.toLowerCase() === '/requestarsip') {
    startArsip(chatId, messageId);
  } else if (receivedTextMessage.toLowerCase() === '/datalahan') {
    startLahan(chatId, messageId);
  } else if (receivedTextMessage.toLowerCase() === '/koordinatsawah') {
    startKoordinatSawah(chatId, messageId);
  } else if (receivedTextMessage.toLowerCase() === '/ceknik') {
    startCekNIK(chatId, messageId);
  } else if (receivedTextMessage.toLowerCase() === '/info') {
    startInfoData(chatId, messageId);
  } else if (receivedTextMessage.toLowerCase() === '/update') {
    startHelpDeskUpdate(chatId, messageId);
  } else if (receivedTextMessage.toLowerCase() === '/help') {
    startHelpDeskCommand(chatId, messageId);
  } else if (receivedTextMessage.toLowerCase() === '/reset') {
    resetScriptProperties();
  } else if (receivedTextMessage.toLowerCase() === '/start') {
    sendTelegramMessage(chatId, messageId, "Halo! Status bot dalam keadaan aktif.");
  } else {
    sendTelegramMessage(chatId, messageId, `Halo!     \n\nSilahkan gunakan perintah /help untuk melihat pilihan perintah yang dapat digunakan`);
  }
}

So, I have a handleCommand function in my code. When I try to use the /requestarsip and /datalahan commands, the function triggers the last else option for me, but the other commands work fine when I use them. I already tried copying the full code into a different App Script file and made a new bot, and all the commands work fine there. I'm very curious about what's wrong and what the difference is between the first file and the new file.

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Instead of the whole code please add a [mcve].

The OP found in the Execution logs that the executed version differed from the most recent. Reviewing the active deployments, they discovered they had multiple active ones. Then they realized that the Telegram bot was not using the deployment with the most recent version (Ref. See the comments in this answer).

Print the arguments object to the Execution logs to confirm that the expected values/objects are assigned to the function parameters. In other words, add console.log(JSON.stringify(arguments));.
Another thing that might be helpful is that you create a function that helps you test and debug your code. If you do this, add the above statement after the `{ from your function.
/**
 * This is to be executed using the debug button after setting an execution break point.
 */
function test_handleTextMessage(){
   const message = "Sample Message", 
   chatId = "sampleChatId", 
   messageId = "sampleMessageId", 
   firstName = "Sample First Name", 
   lastName = "Sample Last Name", 
   userName = "sampleUserName";
   handleTextMessage(message, chatId, messageId, firstName, lastName, userName)
}

function handleTextMessage(message, chatId, messageId, firstName, lastName, userName) {
   console.logs(JSON.stringify(arguments));
   // put here the handleTextMessage's block statements
}

Reference

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting


So, I checked my execution tab, and maybe this is where the problem is. I see that my code is running at version 237, which, if I remember correctly, I deployed months ago. Now, I'm at version 350 or so. When I try to deploy the latest version, the App Script doesn't update to the latest code. Is there any solution for this? Or would it be better to create a new App Script file?

Please open the Editor tab in your Apps Script project, then click Deploy > Manage Deployments. How many active deployments do your project have?

Now I realize, There are 6 active deployments.

I'm glad you found the cause of the problem. I suggest you remove the deployments you are not using and ensure that your Telegram bot uses the correct URL.

Thank you so much for the solution. Deleting the active deployment and running a new one solved the problem, and now my code is running as intended. I was really confused about why it suddenly reverted to the older version when I pushed the newest code, not realizing that I had six active deployments.
